# Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.DBNull' and 'Int'

Tags: c#, error-handling, excel-interop

I am receiving this error when trying to establish a connection with an Excel document to change the colour of all rows that have no fill.

I have read the error log and it states that my error is at the following section of code:

```
try
{
    foreach (Excel.Range row in rows)
    {
        if (row.Cells.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex == -4142) //error is Here
        {
            row.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
    }
    workbook.Save();
    workbook.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}

Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbook);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(worksheet);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(application);
```

Does anyone know what is causing this error and if so how to resolve it?

Comment: According to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.interior.colorindex.aspx) `ColorIndex` is a object (which can be null) and you're comparing it with a number

Comment: @toby It may be an object (most of the Excel object model is like this, yuk) but it will ultimately contain an enumeration value, or be null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If think the easiest fix would be to just use `Equals` instead. As it can compare objects of any type.

```
if (row.Cells.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex.Equals(-4142))
{
   row.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
}
```

Comment: tried this way too and it worked. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5):

That's because the datatype of the object is `System.DBNull`. You should check for a object value type and act accordingly:

```
object objValue = row.Cells.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex;
if(objValue is System.DBNull) {
    // 
} else {
    // 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, tried the code in my project and it worked a charm